# Check if JavaScript object contains X?

Tags: javascript

I need to know if a JavaScript object contains a certain variable.

EG:
Check if 'map' contains 'here'

```
var map = {
    '10': '0',
    '20': '0',
    '30': 'here',
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to loop through the object to test it:

```
var chk = false;
for(var key in map){
    if(map[key] == "here"){
        chk = true;
        break;
    }
}
alert(chk?"Yup":"Nah");
```

You can also put this in `Object` prototype:

```
Object.prototype.ifExist = function(txt){
    var chk = false;
    for(var key in this){
        if(this[key] == txt){
            chk = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return chk;
}

//map.ifExist("here");
//return true
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/yWnYy/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate over the object using the `for..in` syntax:

```
function in_object(value, object) {
    for (var key in map) {
        if (map[key] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here's an example:

```
> in_object('heres', map)
false
> in_object('here', map)
true
```